# New sort criteria "random" for Plone 4 old style collections

Tags: python, collections, plone, zope

is there any best practice for adding a "random" sort criteria to the old style collection in Plone?

My versions:

- Plone 4.3 (4305)
- CMF 2.2.7
- Zope 2.13.19

Comment: just an idea: maybe it's easier to add a custom view that does the random ordering

Answer (score 0):

There is no random sort criteria. Any randomness will need to be done in custom application code.